# Texture is not displayed in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, jogl, texture2d

I have acube and a texture is to be put on all sides.
I did this successfully in a netbeans project, but at the end I got to know that its to be done in eclipse, at first it didn't sound to be a big deal. But the thing is that same code doesn't work in eclipse. The cube is shown but texture is not being applied. heres the code.

```
        public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2(); // Get the GL pipeline object this 
        // GLAutoDrawable uses

        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Set clear color to black
        gl.glClearDepth(1.0f); // Set the depth value to 1.0 (the maximum value),
        // when the depth buffer is cleared

        gl.glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); //Enable depth test

        gl.glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);     
        gl.glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);           


        try {
            texImg = readImage("PWelshDragon.jpg");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
         //   Logger.getLogger(CG0T.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

             gl.glDisable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
             gl.glTexImage2D(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL.GL_RGB, texWidth ,texHeight, 0, GL.GL_RGB, GL.  GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,  texImg);
        gl.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    }
```

In the display code.

```
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();

        gl.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        gl.glRotated(30, 1, 1, 1);

        gl.glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            gl.glNormal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);gl.glTexCoord2d(0.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);gl.glTexCoord2d(1.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);gl.glTexCoord2d(1.0f, 1.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);gl.glTexCoord2d(0.0f, 1.0f);

            gl.glNormal3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);gl.glTexCoord2d(0.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);gl.glTexCoord2d(1.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);gl.glTexCoord2d(1.0f, 1.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);gl.glTexCoord2d(0.0f, 1.0f);


            gl.glNormal3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);gl.glTexCoord2d(0.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);gl.glTexCoord2d(1.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);gl.glTexCoord2d(1.0f, 1.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);gl.glTexCoord2d(0.0f, 1.0f);

            gl.glNormal3f(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);gl.glTexCoord2d(0.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);gl.glTexCoord2d(1.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);gl.glTexCoord2d(1.0f, 1.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);gl.glTexCoord2d(0.0f, 1.0f);

            gl.glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);gl.glTexCoord2d(0.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);gl.glTexCoord2d(1.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);gl.glTexCoord2d(1.0f, 1.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);gl.glTexCoord2d(0.0f, 1.0f );


            gl.glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);gl.glTexCoord2d(0.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);gl.glTexCoord2d(1.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);gl.glTexCoord2d(1.0f, 1.0f);
            gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);gl.glTexCoord2d(0.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glEnd();
    }
```

I'm getting the values in texImg, but dont know why its not being applied.

Comment: Do you have any GlGetError()s in your code? Might help in finding the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, by adding following lines before image drawing code in display function. (before `gl.glBegin(GL_QUADS);`)

```
gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL2.GL_CLAMP);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL2.GL_CLAMP);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL.GL_NEAREST);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL.GL_NEAREST);
gl.glTexEnvi(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_ENV,GL2.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL2.GL_MODULATE);
gl.glHint(GL2.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT,GL2.GL_NICEST);
```

I don't really know, what these lines do. I saw it [here](http://www.it.hiof.no/~borres/j3d/JOGL/tcube/p-tcube.html)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know anything about opengl in Java but could not it simply be your image file "PWelshDragon.jpg" not being loaded because not found or whatever ?

Have you tried to put back the commented line

```
  Logger.getLogger(CG0T.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
```

in the catch to see if there is not a problem here ?